# Application having trouble when opening with network

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

I'm building an app that is using the Instagram API to display photos but I'm running into some trouble. The app is crashing when there is no network connection and I have found the code that is causing the problem.

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
self.accessToken = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"accessToken"];

if (self.accessToken == nil) {
    [SimpleAuth authorize:@"instagram" options:@{@"scope": @[@"likes"]} completion:^(NSDictionary *responseObject, NSError *error) {

        self.accessToken = responseObject[@"credentials"][@"token"];

        [userDefaults setObject:self.accessToken forKey:@"accessToken"];
        [userDefaults synchronize];

        [self refresh];
    }];
} else {

  [self refresh];

}
```

I have found that the `[self refresh];` is causing the problem in the `else` block and I tried to replace it with a alert view like this

```
UIAlertView *networkError = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Network Error" message:@"Please connect your device to a network and restart application" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
[networkError show];
```

However, with this problem I find that if I open the app with a network connection I still get the alert. Any help would be great because I'm still new to Objective C!

Thank you for the help!

Comment: This is what breakpoints are for. For starters, that completion routine has an `error` parameter you never check and you never check the values you extract from `responseObject` before saving them to `NSUserDefaults` (and Objective-C collection classes don't like storing `nil`).  Finally the stacktrace and associated error message are important for this type of question; please add them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this code from Treehouse :).

The thing is that the if (self.accessToken == nil) { /*...*/ } block will only get execute when the app is not authorized using your Instagram credentials.

Once you logged in successfully, it will always execute the code in the else { /*...*/ } block. If it has connection to Internet, it will do its work, download, display images etc. If you insert the code to display alert, it will always do that because you actually mean that by that code.

If you want to check if there is some connection, you need to do that before all that code, display an error and return instantly if connection is not available. However, the author tried to keep things simple, assuming there is always Internet connection.

Hope it makes you understand it.

This is the some code you can use for checking if there is connection:

// show some activity indicator

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
    // Do something...

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com/"];

NSString *s = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url
                                       encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                          error:nil];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    // hide the activity indicator

    self.connected = (s != nil);

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];

    if (self.isConnected)
    {
        NSLog(@"self.connected == YES");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"self.connected == NO");
        NSString *alertMessage = @"In order to load images, you need an active Internet connection. Please try again later!";

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry!"
                                                        message:alertMessage
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [alert show];
    }
});
```

});

You obviously need to add a property to you class. You can insert this code:

```
@interface LDPhotosViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, copy, getter = isConnected) NSString *connected;

@end
```

at the top of LDPhotosViewController.m file, before the @implementation line.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I have one more question! I've added the code in the `- (void)viewDidLoad` and above `  self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
` and right before the `NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];`. However, I am getting an error for `connected` and `isConnected` saying `Property 'connected' not found on object of type 'LDPhotosViewController *'` and `Property 'isConnected' not found on object of type 'LDPhotosViewController *'`. How could I fix this error? Once again thank you very much!